# What databases should I use with Ruby on Rails, based on current Hosting services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I've been looking for hosting services and I still don't know what kind of database is the most commom. It seems to be MySql and PostgreSql. 
So, I'm not sure about how much traffic and data my website will have (it's just a project), but I would like to be prepared. I've worked in some projects with Oracle (PL/SQL) and I know something from MySql.

Thank you !

ps. 4 years later, I've been coding RoR mostly with PostgreSQL. SQLite by default when I need simple apps, but PostgreSQL otherwise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the tenets of Rails is you shouldn't really care what database you're using: that's all abstracted for you.

So I would say go with the hosting provider that seems the overall best, and trust them to pick a good database.

In this case, as house9, I would recommend [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) as an excellent overall service. Start with a small, free plan, scale up as needed. They use PostgreSQL by default, which has been entirely adequate in my experience.

Comment: FYI: Rails sometimes generates SQL that fails in PostgreSQL but would work in MySQL.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend Heroku for hosting
they require Postgres or if you want to go 'NoSql' - you can use MongoDB via the MongoHQ Heroku plug-in

http://heroku.com/

they offer a 'free' plan for small sites

Answer (score 2):

[Engine Yard](http://engineyard.com) is a trusted Rails host.  They support MySQL, Postgres and MongoDB.  Here is their list of supported technologies:

http://www.engineyard.com/technology/stack

On May 10th, they are hosting a demo on their cloud services.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL](http://mysql.com) is by far the most common free web database now a days, and is very common in Ruby on Rails Projects.  Almost all linux hosting providers will give you mysql databases.  Unless you have a specific reason to go elsewhere, it is a great place to start.

I have personally implemented a couple of RoR projects that used MySQL as the backend with no complaints.

Comment: mysql is not actually 'free'; they have  multiple license options, in many cases the hosting provider probably handles the commercial fee, so it might seem free

http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html

Comment: You can download MySQL Community Server under the GPL.  Hard to get much "free-er" than that.  You can't distribute it as a commercial product, but you can host a production database that a commercial website connects to.  If I am wrong, let me know and hopefully this doesn't get too off topic.

Comment: looks like you are correct; I was under the impression that the 'commercial' license was for any commercial use, but that doesn't appear to be the case - distribution only. - sorry for the mis-information. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/02/17/when-are-you-required-to-have-a-commercial-mysql-license/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any argument that MySQL is the most used. If you re looking for an enterprise class database, I say give DB2 a try. Just like MySQL, DB2 Express-C is free and optional support is available. DB2 is the only database that has support from the vendor. See http://antoniocangiano.com/2010/04/22/rails-db2-and-the-enterprise/.